# Jquery: $.when behaves differently depending on number of arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

$.when behaves differently depending on whether one or more Deferred object are passed to it. This behaviour is documented in the docs - but the problem is that it is forcing me to write two different code paths.

```
function foo (dfds) {
    $.when.apply(this, dfds).done(function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
}
```

Case I:

```
foo([$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/8.8.8.8"),
     $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/8.8.8.9")]);
....
/* Output (what I'd come to expect) */
[Array[3], Array[3]]
```

Case II:

```
foo([$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/8.8.8.8")]);
....
/* Output (the original unwrapped deferred's arguments) */
[Object, "success", Object]
```

Any way to elegantly handle this without resorting to checking the length of `dfd` or the type of `arguments`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid explicit testing the number of deferred objects. Assuming you want to return the deferred object:

```
function foo (dfds) {
    if(dfds.length > 1) {
        return $.when.apply(this, dfds);
    }
    else {
        return dfds[0].pipe(function() {
            return [Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)]
        });
    }
}
```

You could create a jQuery plugin to wrap this functionality and make it reusable:

```
(function($) {
    $.when_ = function() {
        if(arguments.length > 1) {
            return $.when.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
            return arguments[0].pipe(function() {
                return [Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)];
            });
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

You could also override `$.when` but I don't know for sure whether it is used internally or not.

Comment: +1, but I won't accept your answer in order to make it explicit for future readers that this problem has no elegant solution (*yet*).

Comment: @Manav: I agree, the API is very inconsistent in this point. But as long as this is not changed in jQuery, you have to check explicitly and if they change it, you don't need a solution anymore ;)

Comment: So how do we get jQuery to change? :)

Comment: @Manav: You could write a bug report (if it does not already exist) :) The only problem I see is that it could break backwards compatibility.

Comment: You were right: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10811 already exists, and the developer seems to have closed it as "invalid" after some pretty vitriolic comments :) Seems like your $.when_ is the best solution as of now.

Comment: Manav is using `$.ajax` whose handlers get 3 parameters, not 1. Copy, paste, and format this code to handle that.
`(function($) {
$.when_ = function() {
if(arguments.length == 1) {
var $deferred = new $.Deferred();
arguments[0].then( 
function Julian_Aubourg_resistance_success() {
$deferred.resolve(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
},
function Julian_Aubourg_assimilation_failure() {
$deferred.reject(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
}
);
return $deferred.promise();
}
else {
return $.when.apply(this, arguments);
}
};
}(jQuery));`
Bannings, DeanOC, and Nicholas rejected my update.

Comment: The else should **return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);** instead of [args].

Comment: @AndrejPavlovic: Almost. Still need to return an array of arrays.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Try this test case: **$.when_(new $.Deferred().resolve(1, 2)).then(function() { console.log(arguments); })** You'll see that your updated solution creates an extra nesting of arrays. There is no need to wrap the arguments array into another array.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a bad habit of messing with arguments logic. In your case, a simple loop would normalize it if you want a callback for each deferred object:

```
$.each(dfds, function() {
    $.when(this).done(function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```

You can also loop the arguments so you don’t have to send an array:

```
function foo() {
    $.each(arguments, function() {
        $.when(this).done(function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you always want to return an array of deferred object, you probably need to check the length of arguments in `foo` like Felix posted, or do something like:

```
function foo() {
    $.when.apply(this, arguments).done(function() {
        var args = $.makeArray(arguments),
            result = args[0].constructor != Array ? [args] : args;
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ht8d/

Comment: This changes the semantics. Your solution would execute the console.log as and when each deferred is resolved, whereas the original intent of the question was to execute the console.log after all the deferreds were resolved.

Comment: OK, so you want an Array of deferreds regardless of arguments, is that correct? It’s not very clear in your question...

Comment: OK I updated my answer, but it seems impossible to do it more elegantly than Felix posted or the last example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just push a dummy object onto the end of your dfds array. That will ensure it always has length 2 or greater, assuming you have at least one deferred.

Comment: then I'd have to add extra logic when iterating over the results to skip over the extra undefined results added. For example, the following code `$.when($.Deferred().resolve(), $.Deferred().resolve()).done(function() {Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(x) {console.log(x)})})` prints `undefined` twice.

Comment: Just always skip the last one, which you know is the sentinel  you added to make sure there are at least two.

Comment: I think you missed my point. That the code which does the iteration will have to have some (maybe minimal) shim to do the skipping. And that's is exactly what the question was trying to avoid :)